# Instead of Carrier Aggregation, why don't carriers use the new frequency bandwidth as separate channel to connect users directly?

Tags: networking, mobile, gsm, bandwidth, lte

Carrier aggregation combines the existing spectrum, say if the carrier had previously 20MHz in the area, with the newly acquired spectrum of 20MHz, to give a wider pipe or bandwidth for data flow between the mobile device & the base station tower.

My question is, why don't they just operate the new bandwidth as a separate pipe? So that there would be two pipes of 20MHz each, instead of one aggregated pipe of 40MHz?

Benefits:

1. Carriers won't have to deal with the complexity of Carrier Aggregation technology, as the two bands are totally separate (2300MHz & 1800MHz). End-users can be divided over the two frequencies. Theoretically this should halve the load on one channel, providing double the speeds to connected users.
2. Many existing 4G devices use single antenna for 4G operation. The LTE-A tech needs MIMO support on both mobile & tower to work. Essentially it needs 2 antennas on both mobile & tower for operating 2 different frequencies, which only stresses the mobile device. Existing hardware cannot benefit from LTE-A, where speeds will continue to remain the same post upgradation. In fact, it may slightly decrease post LTE-A implementation, since newer LTE-A devices will share load on both the frequencies, but existing LTE users can only use one.

For those new, this simple image explains how Carrier Aggregation works. https://www.techtalkthai.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/qualcomm_carrier_aggregation.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1) Assuming that the operator already has 2 bands, it is really not complex to enable and configure carrier aggregation. It is likely that they already have the ability as part of the latest LTE software upgrades and it is just a matter of configuring it and possibly paying for a license to use it.

The scenario you describe of using two separate pipes instead of a single CA pipe is not feasible (or may not be possible?). When a device establishes a connection in an LTE network, a default bearer is configured which would not be able to simultaneously use two radio connections without CA or other similar features. Multiple bearers can certainly be established simultaneously, however they serve different purposes (e.g. voice vs data). That said, really CA *is* using two different pipes, but they act as a single (logical) bearer. Another advantage of CA is that the control plane signaling takes place on only one of the component carriers and therefore the other component carriers can be fully dedicated to user plane traffic.

2) I'll clear a few things up:

- MIMO has nothing to do with Carrier Aggregation.
- Most 4G devices today *transmit* on a single antenna and *receive* on two antennas. (Although they most likely have at least 2 tx and 2 rx antennas, and many have 4 tx and 4 rx antennas, although 4x4 MIMO has not been implemented by most operators.)
- Existing devices are already taking advantage of LTE-A features and some operators are currently rolling out 3-carrier CA, 4x4 MIMO as well as 256QAM.

Here is a recent news article which discusses LTE-A features which have already been implemented: https://newsroom.t-mobile.com/news-and-blogs/lte-advanced.htm

Comment: Not true for TDD devices, they use the same antenna for both Tx & Rx. Hence 2 antennas in CA mode.

Comment: The number of antennas has nothing to do with carrier aggregation. Doesn't matter which type of duplexing you use.